# When called from within my c program, how do I pass data to zlib's zpipe executable, which uses stdin/stdout?

Tags: linux, pipe, stdin, zlib, execve

I have an c program application that is able to generate a file containing compressed data, which is then converted to zlib format by adding the necessary zlib headers and footers. I want to verify that the data has been compressed correctly by invoking zlib's zpipe executable from within my application.

To invoke zpipe directly from a linux command line, the syntax is as follows:  zpipe usage: zpipe [-d] < source > dest, where ‘-d’ signifies decompression. The contents of the source file is therefore directed to stdin and the inflated data to stdout, using the linux command line shell.

My application has its own main function. Initially, I was able to build the zpipe source code into my application and incorporate the necessary code from zpipe's main function into my application's main function, thereby calling zpipe's inflate and deflate functions directly.

Rather than incorporating the zpipe source code itself, what I now want to do instead, is to call the zpipe executable itself from within my application's main function.

I invoke my own application’s main function from a linux command line as follows:
./myapp ./zpipe -d -i zlib_format_input_compressed_file -o output_decompressed_file

I am able to invoke the zpipe executable from within my application, by constructing a newargv however this operation will be unsuccessful until I can actually get zpipe to decompress the file data I give it.

```
    char *newargv[] = {argv[1], argv[2]};   // for zpipe, argc = 2

    if (0 == (my_pid = fork())) {
        if (-1 == execve(argv[1], newargv, NULL)) {
            perror("child process execve failed [%m]");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

The problem is, how do I feed the contents of ‘zlib_format_input_compressed_file’ to zpipe’s stdin from within my c program, just as was done from the command line shell, and tell zpipe to direct the result to output_decompressed_file.  Can I use ‘pipe’ to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this example which in principle is probably forms the basis of what I am trying to do. Two pipes need to be created.
https://jineshkj.wordpress.com/2006/12/22/how-to-capture-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-of-child-program/